# AWS Lambda and API Gateway plus SOAP Client

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, soap, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm new to the AWS Lambda world, and I'm trying to figure out if what I'm trying to do is achievable using AWS web services.

The situation that I have is that a SaaS site will be sending JSON data whenever an event happens on their end, so I what I need to do is have a Restful API (using AWS API Gateway I'm assuming) that can handle CRUD events (e.g. a new employee is added / updated / deleted in the SaaS site, then AWS API gateway will route the event in AWS as such: example.com/employee/create or example.com/employee/update). I'm assuming AWS API Gateway routes the event to its corresponding Lambda function? Does this mean that there must be multiple lambda functions for each CRUD event? Or is this the standard?

If my assumption is correct and the event is sent to its corresponding lambda function, then the next thing that needs to happen is for the Lambda function to basically transform the data, or prepare the data, and talk to another final Site (site B) via a SOAP Client. So in retrospect, in this step the lambda function will eventually send the transformed data via SOAP client.

Functional summary: SaaS ---> [AWS-API-Gateway ---> AWS Lambda ---> Soap Client] --> Site B

Is this entire scenario even possible? In addition to this, there will be occasions when the site with the SOAP API will also need to send information back to the SaaS site.

My language of choice is Java using the Eclipse AWS toolkit. Can I also use any Java SOAP client when developing my lambda functions? Are there any examples out there I could reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SaaS ---> [AWS-API-Gateway ---> AWS Lambda ---> Soap Client] --> Site B

This architecture should work. You'll have to figure out a way to authenticate the SaaS site to api gateway (Using api keys/custom authorizer).

You can use a single lambda function to push the event to site b using the client and return a response. Any public java soap client will work. You need to compile the entire program into a jar and upload it as a lambda function.

One thing you might want to look at is using just API Gateway to talk to Site B since API Gateway can transform request/response - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question

Comment: @user1370897 which method did you go for in the end? I am doing a similar project right now where I need to integrate my rest requests with a SOAP service. Im thinking API Gateway --> Lambda --> Soap Client --> Service